# How to get a value from multi dimension json array in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, firebase, laravel-5

I'm developing a RESTfull API's that gets it's data from firebase database
i successfully retrieved the data exactly like this

```
{
"Admin": {
    "-L-ck6q9elghYywXHneg": {
        "accepted": false,
        "date": "7/12/2017",
        "hour": "4:32",
        "numberOfPeople": "3",
        "tableInfo": ""
    }
},
"Guest": {
    "-KvJja_r0beLtdoRc29f": {
        "accepted": true,
        "date": "1/10/2017",
        "hour": "0:43",
        "numberOfPeople": "",
        "tableInfo": ""
    }
}
```

}

now, i want to access the "accepted" field in both records without knowing the key which is "Admin" or "Guest" how could this be done?

i tried this

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
        $data[$counter]['accepted'] = $user->accepted;
        $counter++;
    }
```

but it was unsuccessful

Comment: There's a `-L-ck6q9elghYywXHneg` key which should be used.

Comment: this key is not known , i mean it changes for each user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this, works perfectly with your data:

```
$users = json_decode($users, true);
foreach ($users as $user) {
   $data[$counter]['accepted'] = array_first($user)['accepted'];
   $counter++;
}
```

Comment: you are great, you made my day it is now working like a charm thanks

Answer (score 0):

It 's an object so do sth like this

```
foreach ($users as $key=>$user) { //changed this line
    $data[$counter]['accepted'] = $user->accepted;
    $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **$user[0]->accepted**

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $data[$counter]['accepted'] = $user[0]->accepted;
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: it throws this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Is your data JSON object or is it a JSON array?

Comment: it is json object